# OPS-008: OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility requires Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 1 Object Model or above

Tags: azure-devops, opshub, tfs-migration

This tool looks promising when I went through the available information on website. But when I downloaded free version and when I am trying to install in my local I came across the following error.

OPS-008: OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility requires Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 1 Object Model or above.

Do I need to install this software on the server ? No where I could find instructions for installing this software.
Can I get this explained please, we are planning to migrate our project to VSTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to migrate from TFS on premise to VSTS, I would suggest you to evaluate which of [the three options listed by Microsoft documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/adopting-vsts) suite your need.

The easier way would be to chose [option 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/migrate-tfs-vsts/?utm_source=ms&utm_medium=guide&utm_campaign=vstsdataimportguide), especially if you already have TFS2015update3 or TFS 2017, as you need to upgrade your TFS collection to one of those version anyway before migrating (and you save the upgrade hassle).

If you want to use OpsHub tool, then you need to install the [standalone TFS Object Model for TFS 2012 update 4](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErinDormierMSFT.TeamFoundationServer2012Update4ObjectModelInstalle) where you run the OpsHub tool, *not* on any of the TFS servers.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run OVSMU, you will have to install [TFS Object Model 2012](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErinDormierMSFT.TeamFoundationServer2012Update4ObjectModelInstalle) on the machine where you are installing the tool. This is a pre-requisite and be rest assured this version of OM will not conflict with any other (newer) version of Object Model already existing (which comes bundled with Visual Studio installer) on that machine.

Comment: is the TFS Object Model 2013.5 not supported then?

Comment: There does exist a forward support for OM 2013. (ie. In case the machine already has that installed, the tool will refer to libraries pertaining to that version).  However, for fresh installation we recommend OM 2012 since that is what the tool is built against.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. I will update my answer with the information your provided, thanks a lot for your support